# NPM 6.13.4 After the update, npm starts and the js node closes immediately, the server reacts to the native server, what should I do?

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

After the upgrade, npm starts and closes the node js react native server immediately, what should I do?

```
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 6 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

Task :app:installDebug
07:44:24 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
07:44:24 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:44:24 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Nexus_S_API_28(AVD) - 9' for app:debug
07:44:24 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
07:44:24 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'emulator-5554'
07:44:24 D/ddms: Reading file permision of D:\cait\nativeTs\App\test\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
as: rwx------
07:44:24 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
07:44:24 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:44:24 V/ddms: execute: returning
07:44:24 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
07:44:24 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:44:24 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 53s
27 actionable tasks: 27 executed
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.test/.MainActivity }
Done in 61.77s.
```

Comment: Can you specify the version of react-native-cli and RN

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion around [yarn] and [yarnpkg].